# Spring security custom login form issue

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

When making post request to login controller url (/api/auth) I recieve index.html in response. 
My security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.
                inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/assets/**","/index.html","/css/**","/js/**","/views/**","/bower_components/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/api/auth")
                .permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

My angular controller:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {

var authenticate = function (credentials, callback) {

    var headers = credentials ? {authorization: "Basic " + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)} : {};

    credentials ? console.log(credentials.username + " " + credentials.password) : console.log("empty credentials")
    //console.log(header);
    $http.post('/#/api/auth', {"headers":headers}).success(function (data) {
        if (data.name) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
            console.log("in authenticate " + data.name)
        } else {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            console.log("in authenticate data in null")
        }
        callback && callback();
    }).error(function () {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        console.log("error in authenticate")
        callback && callback();
    });
}
authenticate();
$scope.credentials = {};
$scope.login = function () {
    authenticate($scope.credentials, function () {
        if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
            $location.path("/");
            console.log("in callback " + $scope.credentials)
            $scope.error = false;
        } else {
            $location.path("/api/auth");
            console.log("error in callback")
            $scope.error = true;
        }
    });
};

})
```

My rest controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LoginLogoutController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/auth")
    public void home(@RequestBody String wrap){
        System.out.println(wrap);
    }
```

Spring security logs (this logs appear when I try to post login and password):

```
20:48:06.469 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@11dc2a2b
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/index.html'; against '/logout'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/index.html'; against '/api/auth'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
20:48:06.470 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
20:48:06.471 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
20:48:06.471 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
20:48:06.471 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
20:48:06.471 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/index.html'; against '/assets/**'
20:48:06.471 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/index.html'; against '/index.html'
20:48:06.471 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /index.html; Attributes: [permitAll]
20:48:06.471 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
20:48:06.474 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@152d862b, returned: 1
20:48:06.474 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
20:48:06.474 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
20:48:06.474 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.html reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
20:48:06.474 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
20:48:06.474 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
20:48:06.474 [http-apr-8090-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Other rest endpoints work fine. Spring default login form works great but issue appears when I try to run with custom login form.

Comment: So what is the problem with this ? Your are not getting authenticated or incorrect page is opened or the home() method is not called ?

Comment: home() method is not being called

Comment: The logs say : you asked for **`/index.html`** while not being logged, as `/index.html` has an explicit `permitAll`, you were logged as an anonymous user and the asked page was directly returned without requiring a login.